# How do i mock a Interface with Moq or NInject Mocking Kernel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, ninject, moq

I just waded through questions and blogs on the subject of mocking and Dependency Injection. Come to a conclusion i just need to mock the interface that is consumed by client. I am looking forward to testing a simple use case here with no idea.

**The Contract**

```
public Interface IApplicationService
{

     bool DeleteApplication(int id);

     ApplicationDto AddApplication(ApplicationDto application);

     IEnumerable<ApplicationDto> GetApplications();

}
```

**Implementation ( I am going to mock )**

```
public Class ApplicationService:IApplicationService
{
    private EntityFrameworkRepo repo; 

    public ApplicationService()
    {
         repo = new EntityFrameworkRepo();
    }

    public ApplicationDto Add(ApplicationDto dto)
    {
         //add to dbcontext and commit
    }

}
```

**Mocking Code**

```
[Test(Description = "Test If can successfully add application")]
public void CanAddApplication()
{
    //create a mock application service
    var applicationService = new Mock<IApplicationService>();

    //create a mock Application Service to be used by business logic
    var applicationDto = new Mock<ApplicationDto>();

    //How do i set this up
    applicationService.Setup(x => x.GetApplications()).Returns(IEnumerable<applicationDto.Object>);
}
```

And i for one am sure i need to test the business logic rather than mocking it. So what is it exactly i have to do to test my `ApplicationService` but then keep the entity framework out.

btw to speak of `ApplicationService`, it uses constructor injection with NInject. So mocking this with `NInject.MockingKernel` will setup dependency chain?

Comment: It looks like you are a little confused between testing and mocking. You should not mock the class which you want to test, just its dependencies.

Comment: @gt Exactly :) I am confused. So in my case what should i be actually mocking ? and any code to explain further would really help me through

Comment: I'm not familiar with ninject so I can't help you there, but it looks like you should create an instance of `ApplicationService`, then 'inject' it with a mock `repo` and/or `dto` object. Then you can test whether the correct calls were made on the these mocks, using the `Verify` call. You're nearly there!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is little or no benefit using dependency injection (IOC) container in unit testing. Dependency injection helps you in creating loose coupled components, and loose coupled components are easier to test, thats it.

So if you want to test some service, just create mockups of it dependencies and pass them to that service as usual (no need to involve IOC container here, I hardly can imagine, that you will need some features of IOC containers - like contextual binding, interception etc. - inside unit test).

**If you want your `ApplicationService` to be easy to test, it should look more like:**

```
public class ApplicationService: IApplicationService
{
    private readonly IEntityFrameworkRepo repo; 

    // dependency passed by constructor
    public ApplicationService(IEntityFrameworkRepo repo)
    {
         this.repo = repo;
    }

    // save to db when DTO is eligible
    public ApplicationDto Add(ApplicationDto dto)
    {
         // some business rule
         if(dto.Id > 0 && dto.Name.Contains(string.Empty)){
              //add to dbcontext and commit
         }else{
              throw new NotEligibleException();
         } 
    }   
}
```

*Here the dependency is passed by constructor. In your application code you will use it together with an IOC container to make constructor injection (IOC container will be responsible for creating instances of `IEntityFrameworkRepo`).*

*But in unit test, you can just pass instance of some implementation of `IEntityFrameworkRepo` created on your own.*

**`ApplicationDto`**

*As long as `ApplicationDto` is some object that can by created by hand, I can directly use it in unit-test (creating instances by hand). Otherwise I will have to wrap it by interface like `IApplicationDto`, in order to be able to mock it up with Moq.*

```
public class ApplicationDto{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

**Here is how could unit-test look like:**

*In unit test I will use mocked implementaion of `IApplicationRepo`, because I do not want to configure e.g. database connections, web services etc. and my primary intention is to test the `ApplicationService` not the underlying repository. Another advantage is that the test will be runnable without specific configuration for various machines. To mockup some db repository I can use e.g. `List`.*

```
[Test(Description = "Test If can successfully add application")]
public void CanAddApplicationIfEligible()
{
    var repo = GetRepo();
    var appService = new ApplicationService(repo);       
    var testAppDto = new ApplicationDto() { Id = 155, Name = "My Name" };

    var currentItems = repo.ApplicationDtos.Count();

    appService.Add(testAppDto);

    Assert.AreEqual(currentItems + 1, repo.ApplicationDtos.Count());
    var justAdded = repo.ApplicationsDto.Where(x=> x.Id = 155).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.IsNotNull(justAdded);
    ///....
}

private static IEntityFrameworkRepo GetRepo{
    // create a mock repository
    var listRepo = new List<ApplicationDto>{
                         new ApplicationDto {Id=1, Name="MyName"}               
                   };

    var repo = new Mock<IEntityFrameworkRepo>();

    // setup the methods you know you will need for testing

    // returns initialzed list instead of DB queryable like in real impl.
    repo.Setup(x => x.ApplicationDtos)
        .Returns<IQueryable<ApplicationDto>>(x=> listRepo);

    // adds an instance of ApplicationDto to list
    repo.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<ApplicationDto>())
        .Callback<ApplicationDto>(a=> listRepo.Add(a));
    return repo.Object;
}
```

Note:

*There have been realeased an [ninject.mockingkernel](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.mockingkernel/wiki/Examples) extension. The approach described in example on wiki can make your unit-test code bit tidier, but the approach described there is definetly not depencdency injection (it is service locator).*

Comment: *"no need to use the dependency injection (...)"* - DI is not something you turn on or off. You either have class design supporting it or you don't. Using DI container in unit tests makes little sense (as you noted), but DI alone is abstract concept not (necessarily) related to any container.

Comment: I agree, rewrited it to *no need to involve IOC container*, which better describes what I meant.

Comment: @mipe34 could you include code to mock `applicationDto`,I still feel what is the use of unit testing if the output is predictable using a mocking framework. Which states return this when that happens. Mocking framework will do it right, hhmmm ahhhh totally lost in unit testing now

Comment: @Deeptechtons You don't have to mock-up `ApplicationDto` unless it is some hard to create by hand or hard to configure object with lot of dependencies. Look at my updated example in the answer, hope it helps you better to understand. Keep in mind, that you typicaly use mocks instead of real implementations of objects, that are hard to maintain, create or configure inside the unit-test.

Comment: @mipe34 just plain wonderful. If there is any example with lazy loading( of entity framework) it would be great +1 marked as answer. I have used lazy loading at many methods

Comment: @Deeptechtons lazy loading is a way how EF can load dependent objects. When you mock-up the db context or repository you will have to construct the exptected object tree (object dependencies you need for testing) at your own. But concept of lazy loading should not influence your unit tests in general.